# How to make Author mode component annotations visible in CQ5/AEM5.6.1?

Tags: aem

In AEM 5.6.1, if I add annotation to the component it works just fine while I'm editing the page but disappears after page is reloaded.

[image]

There is no difference if it is custom or out-of-the-box component, if page was activated or not, annotation is just not loading.

CRXDE Lite shows that cq:annotations node has been successfully created

[image]

Is there any configuration switch which should be turned on in order to load annotations?

Answer (score 0):

After debugging CQ/ExtJS scripts it turned out that PageInfo provider is not returning .annotations property and condition on line #396 of /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm/EditBase.js was always false. Further debugging showed that our custom overlay of foundation/components/page lacked proper node type and it was the reason for omission of the annotations InfoProvider polling. Strange enough it didn't affect any other info provider (languages, msm, workflows, ...), just annotations.

More info: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/pageinfo.html

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar - copying the cq:InfoProviders node from libs/foundation/components/page to the same node as my custom page node corrected it.